# Importing a CSV file that has no headers via ADO into VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, csv, import-from-csv

I have an old COBOL system that spits out Simple CSV files. These files have no headers. i.e. all lines in the CSV are data/record sets.

I have the code to import the CSV file into VBA and pop it into an array. All works well but I lose the first line of data because it thinks it is a header row.

the SQL string I am using is SELECT * FROM Data.CSV

Shall I just pull the fields and script a work around or is there a more elegant solution.

thanks in advance for reading this post.

Comment: Modify the VBA code so that it doesn't drop the first row, surely.

Comment: Have you tried `HDR=NO` in the extended properties of the connection string?

Comment: thanks hobo but its seems not that simple.

Comment: I have tried HDR= NO but now I'm getting a EOF/BOF error, I get EOF = true and I can't pull the record sets.

Comment: Have sorted it, just a silly error. thanks to Barrowc, I'm not great at SQL, should really brush up on it.

Comment: Hi @barrowc I think your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `HDR=NO` in the extended properties of the connection string should fix that error